# How to get grand total of matched Left Join items in SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am struggling to find a way to get a GRAND TOTAL count of the number of rows matched in a LEFT JOIN.

This is the current query:

```
SELECT * FROM renewal
LEFT JOIN appointment ON appointment.renewalid=renewal.id
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(app.id) AS appcount FROM renewal
LEFT JOIN appointment ON appointment.renewalid=renewal.id
```

But that is obviously not the right way, as it only returns the total appointments for each renewal row returned.

I have also tried a subquery:

```
SELECT customer.*, app.totalcount FROM renewal
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(id) AS appcount FROM appointment) AS app ON app.renewalid=renewal.id
```

This also is not working.

Currently, I can get it to return the total for each customer, but not a GRAND TOTAL.

The reason I am not just querying the appointments table alone, is because I need it only to return a grand total of appointments linked to customers which follow the specified OUTER 'WHERE' statement.

**Disclaimer**: The queries above are a much more simplified version, just for readability sakes.

Here is the full query:

```
SELECT
    renewal.id AS renid,
    renewal.personid,
    renewal.enddate,
    renewal.assettype,
    renewal.producttype,
    renewal.vrm,
    renewal.make,
    renewal.model,
    renewal.submodel,
    renewal.derivative,
    renewal.complete,
    person.forename,
    person.surname,
    person.company,
    appointment.id AS appid,
    COUNT(appointment.renewalid) AS appointedcount,
    appointment.renewalid,
    n.latestnote,
    (
    SELECT
        COUNT(complete)
    FROM
        renewal
    WHERE
        complete = 1 && enddate BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-30' && dealershipid = '1' && assettype = 'N' && producttype NOT LIKE '%CH%' && complete = 1
) AS renewedcount
FROM
    renewal
LEFT JOIN person ON person.id = renewal.personid
LEFT JOIN appointment ON appointment.renewalid = renewal.id
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT
        note AS latestnote,
        TIMESTAMP,
        renewalid
    FROM
        renewal_note
    ORDER BY
        TIMESTAMP
    DESC
) AS n
ON
    n.renewalid = renewal.id
WHERE
    enddate BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-30' && renewal.dealershipid = '1' && assettype = 'N' && producttype NOT LIKE '%CH%'
GROUP BY
    renid
ORDER BY
    enddate ASC
```

This is what is being outputted with the Full query (Removed cluttering columns which arent relevant to this question):

```
| renid  | appid  | appointedcount  | renewedcount  |  |
|--------|--------|-----------------|---------------|--|
|  60177 |   1096 |               6 |             5 |  |
|  64704 |   2470 |               6 |             5 |  |
|  43057 |        |               0 |             5 |  |
|  64626 |        |               0 |             5 |  |
|  11123 |        |               0 |             5 |  |
|  72469 |        |               0 |             5 |  |
|  76055 |   2879 |               7 |             5 |  |
|  76001 |   2546 |               3 |             5 |  |
|  72171 |   2769 |               6 |             5 |  |
|  76073 |        |               0 |             5 |  |
|  73183 |   2093 |               8 |             5 |  |
|  73114 |   2834 |               6 |             5 |  |
|  43088 |        |               0 |             5 |  |
|    732 |        |               0 |             5 |  |
|  11157 |        |               0 |             5 |  |
|  60207 |        |               0 |             5 |  |
|  73103 |   2015 |               3 |             5 |  |
|  75982 |        |               0 |             5 |  |
|  43076 |        |               0 |             5 |  |
```

It seems like the highest appointedcount value is 8, which if you count the number of rows with an appid (an appointment), adds up to 8. 
I believe I am heading in the right direction, as it is returning 8 (at a random renewal row), but can't seem to get past this point.

Can someone please guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a window function:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(a.id) OVER () AS total_appcount
FROM renewal r LEFT JOIN
     appointment a
     ON a.renewalid = r.id ;
```

In older versions of MySQL, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM renewal r JOIN
             appointment a
             ON a.renewalid = r.id
       ) AS total_appcount
FROM renewal r LEFT JOIN
     appointment a
     ON a.renewalid = r.id ;
```

Note that for the subquery, you don't need an outer join, because you only want matches.

Comment: php my admin throws an error before i can even hit execute sql...
When i remove  OVER() it lets me execute

Comment: @MaxResnikoff . . . Then you are using an older version of MySQL.